# Javascript - why is this function value not reset on every call

Tags: javascript

I have made a jsbin to demonstrate what i mean. why does count incrament? I though on every call to a function all internal variables are reset.

http://jsbin.com/kilonepece/edit?html,js,console,output

```
function test(text) {
  var count = 0;

  return function() {
    console.log(text + ' ' + count);
    count++;
  }
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', test('clicked'));
```

this results in this logged to the console.

"clicked 0"
"clicked 1"
"clicked 2"
"clicked 3"
"clicked 4"

and so on

Comment: `count` is set to `0` at each call to `test()`

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, not a jsfiddle. [mcve] A fiddle can compliment your example but not be used in its stead.

Comment: `count` is external to the anonymous function.

Comment: `test` is only being called *once*.  The function it returns, which holds a reference to the `count` variable, is being called multiple times.  There is only one `count`, and it's incremented each time that function is called.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you invoke `test` the `count` will reset. What you're doing is invoking `test` once and assigning the returned function as the event handler. This makes is so the event handler has a value of `0` for `count` to start, then increments that value on every click.

`count` is not an "internal" variable to the closure, only to the `test` function which you're invoking only once.

Answer (score -1):

This should always reset it. Please try the below:

```
function test(text) {
    var count = 0;
    return function() {
    console.log(text + ' ' + count);
    count++;
}()
}
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', test('clicked'));
```

Comment: This executes the inner function once (when the page loads) and then sets the click handler to `undefined`.

Comment: How can the inner function be called when the page loads without being called or without clicking the button element?

Comment: Because you added parentheses to the end of the `return` statement in the outer function.  Parentheses *execute* a function.  So now the return value of `test()` is the return value of the inner function, which doesn't return anything.  (So, `undefined`)  Test your code and see.